# How to add two lists like matlab in Haskell?

Tags: matlab, haskell

I was wondering if it is possible to write a Haskell add operator that can work on two numbers, two lists of numbers, two matrices of numbers, ... and so on. That is, is it possible to define an `<+>` such that all of the following works?:

```
1 <+> 2 = 3
[1] <+> [2] = [3]
[[1]] <+> [[2]] = [[3]]
...
```

I know that as in [What is an idiomatic way to add lists in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776750/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-to-add-lists-in-haskell) , we can do `+` for `a`, `zipWith (+)` for `[a]`. Probably `zipWith (zipWith (+))` for `[[a]]`, along the same line, and so on...

But can it be done using one operator (as Matlab was able) using type classes or other features of Haskell?

I know this is syntatic sugar, but it would be sweet if possible.

-- update --

I see that maybe it's problematic to use `(Num a)` as explained in @DanielWagner's answer, and it's probably the best to define it individually for `Integer, Double` etc. for base cases.

Just for the record, I just tried as suggested:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
class Additive a where (<+>) :: a -> a -> a
instance Num a => Additive a where (<+>) = (+)
instance Additive a => Additive [a] where (<+>) = zipWith (<+>)
```

Or

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
class Additive a where
    (<+>) :: a -> a -> a
    default (<+>) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
    (<+>) = (+)
```

In either case, there is an error when loading the `.hs` file or when evaluating `[[1,2]] <+> [[3,4]]`.

Comment: Well, you could probably write a class much like `Monoid` with different instances.

Comment: To make this interesting, you need to provide more thorough examples. What do you want `[1,2] <+> [3,4]` to give? What about `[[1,2],[3,4]] <+> [[5,6],[7,8]]`? What about `[1,2,3,4] <+> []`? There are lots of edge cases to consider.

Comment: Matlab/Octave will give dimensions don't match error in the last example, otherwise it's an `X(i,j) + Y(i,j)`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Matlab behavior is what I had in mind: element-wise operation to be precise. But I guess the tolerance of zipWith would be nice too, depending on each user.

Comment: @tinlyx The reason your attempt to use @DanielWagner's answer didn't work is that you left `LANGUAGE` out of your compiler pragmas. Instead of `{-# FlexibleInstances #-}`, try `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}`.

Comment: Even if it's possible, it's a bad idea. Matlab actually proves that point well enough, if you ask me...

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think it's a bad idea for Matlab because dimensions are collapsed arbitrarily to allow e.g.  1 + [2]. Not the case here?

Comment: @tinlyx: yeah, I suppose it's not _that_ bad. But still you'll have either runtime errors (as in Matlab), or silent extension with zeroes (as _sometimes_ in Matlab), or cutoff of significant elements (as with `zipWith`) whenever some length doesn't match. IMO it's better to make that possibility explicit by actually using `zip`s or something else as appropriate when you have dynamic-length lists, and only use [shorthand operators for vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) (including scalars or linear operators) where the dimension is confirmed to match at compile-time.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Agreed. Probably a variant of `zipWith` that checks for dimensions or ensures dimensions are the same (at run time), or even fancier techniques to check it at compile time if that is possible? That's probably beyond this question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
class Additive a where (<+>) :: a -> a -> a
instance Additive Integer where (<+>) = (+)
instance Additive a => Additive [a] where (<+>) = zipWith (<+>)
```

Your three test cases in ghci:

```
*Main> 1 <+> 2
3
*Main> [1] <+> [2]
[3]
*Main> [[1]] <+> [[2]]
[[3]]
```

If you want lots of instances where `(<+>) = (+)`, you can make this a default implementation with `DefaultSignatures`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
class Additive a where
    (<+>) :: a -> a -> a
    default (<+>) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
    (<+>) = (+)
```

The advantage is that some instances can be quite short, e.g.

```
instance Additive Integer
instance Additive Int
instance Additive Double
instance Additive Float
```

will all work as expected without any additional method definitions.

Comment: Any elegant way to replace `Integer` with `Num`?

Comment: Sure: `instance Num a => Additive a where (<+>) = (+)`

Comment: @ReinHenrichs that works only with `FlexibleInstances` enabled right?

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov Yes, but `FlexibleInstances` is certainly part of the common GHC dialect of Haskell.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov In fact you need `UndecidableInstances` too, but afaik this is a safe use. It's only letting the compiler know that it's ok that `Additive` is the same size as `Num`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Won't that instance overlap with the `[]` one?

Comment: Could you show how to make `Num a` work? Please see my update

Comment: @tinlyx You cannot, in general, make this work with `Num a` as the base case. Instead make instances of `Additive` for each type you care about -- `Int`, `Double`, whatever. (Consider what should happen if I write `instance Num a => Num [a] where ...`!)

Comment: @tinlyx ...although it occurs to me that `DefaultSignatures` would at least make those instances quite short. I'll add a comment about this to my answer.

Comment: As nice as `DefaultSignatures` is sometimes, it really annoys me. The class needs to choose just one lucky context to get the free default. Blech.